# Why cannot catch error in redux-saga generator?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

Here is store/store.js

```
...

const initSagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [initSagaMiddleware, fetchPhotosMiddleware, putPhotoMiddleware];
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

...

initSagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

sagas/api-saga.js

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        photoWatcher()
    ]);
}

function* photoWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(PUT_PHOTO, putPhotoWorker);
}

function* putPhotoWorker(action) {
    try {
        const payload = yield call(putPhoto, action.urlParams, action.body);
        yield put({ type: PHOTO_UPDATED, payload });
    } catch (err) {
        yield put({ type: API_ERROR_PUT_PHOTO, payload: err });
    }
}
```

and services/api.js

```
export function putPhoto(urlParams, body) {
    return axios.put('/abc/' + urlParams.key + '/def/' + urlParams.id + '/edit', body)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => err);
}
```

My problem is: even when I get error from an api call, redux-saga `put`ting `PHOTO_UPDATED` instead of `API_ERROR_PUT_PHOTO`. What am I doing wrong? How to catch error?

Comment: The problem is you are catching the error in the `putPhoto` function. Just remove the catch and it should work. Probably.

Comment: Nope. It didn't work :/

Comment: does the API throw an error?

Comment: sure. 400 Bad Request.

Comment: If you leave the promise `catch` in the putPhoto function, is the catch callback called when the error happens? (Put console.log or smth inside to check).

Comment: yes, `catch` promise in `putPhoto` is catching the error. Now I'm using the `if...else` instead of `try...catch` as in below.

Comment: @RıdvanSumset could you verify if the response type thrown is of [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) type?

Comment: @MartinKadlec u were right from the beginning! If I remove `catch` inside `putPhoto` then the `catch` inside api-saga is able to catch the error. And actual problem is, after getting `400` api error, my custom middleware throws an error because there is no length of data (cannot make for loop on undefined)

Comment: I can accept your first comment as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RıdvanSumset great, I added an answer so its easier to see. Glad you figured it out in the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to catch the same error twice. Just remove the catch form the `putPhoto` function and it should work.

```
export function putPhoto(urlParams, body) {
    return axios.put('/abc/' + urlParams.key + '/def/' + urlParams.id + '/edit', body)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `then` and `catch` promises in `putPhoto` func were resulting in `try` statement. Because of that, I give up on `try...catch`, instead I'm using `if...else` statement now. Like this:

```
function* putPhotoWorker(action) {
    const payload = yield call(putPhoto, action.urlParams, action.body);
    if (isResponseTypeWhatIExpected) {
        yield put({ type: PHOTO_UPDATED, payload });
    } else {
        yield put({ type: API_ERROR_PUT_PHOTO, payload });
    }
}
```

Comment: I put my answer here, if anyone faces an issue like this, so that they can workaround. I don't accept it as it is not direct answer to the question.